# Postgres Column Value Unique to User

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my app I have `users` and `tags`. Tags have a `name` property (tag.name).

I want to enforce unique tag names per user. Meaning a user cannot have two matching strings in the `name` column. Tag name uniqueness is only account specific. Meaning user 1 and user 2 can both have a `tag.name` equal to `Tag1`

I only know of two ways to do this. Before saving, fetch all the tags for the user and make sure the incoming tag names do not create duplicates. Or, create a new column that is a combination of the user.id + tag.name aka `1-tag1` and set the column as `UNIQUE`.

Is there a better way to do this? If not, which of my two strategies seems best?

Comment: you cant make user.id and tag.name a composite key?

Comment: @Kaus2b that was one of my suggestions..

Comment: no,  unless my eyes deceive me, you said add a new column thats a concat of two fields. You dont need to do that. You can make two columns as part of a Unique constraint

Comment: @Kaus2b sorry, new to SQL. After looking up composite key I see what you mean now. This is exactly what I want, ty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
      (
               id INTEGER NOT NULL,
               tag_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
               PRIMARY KEY(id),
               CONSTRAINT some_name UNIQUE (id, tag_name)
      );
```

you can also make the two columns together as a primary key by doing this:

```
PRIMARY KEY(id, tag_name)
```

but I don't like that approach personally. I prefer primary keys to be the integer ID columns to use auto-increment and other fancy features without much configs.